# Update the value of a cell in Dataframe based off a cell value in the next row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add an upper bound column to my dataframe. The conditions of the upper bound for the row is the next rows "From Quantity" -1 and the last row just defaults to 1000.
[image]

Ive used the following code and it works just fine but when the data is not organized correctly it fails and it also doesnt cover the final line

```
for i in range(len(df_p)):
        if( i < (len(df_p)-1)):
            df_p.iloc[i, df_p.columns.get_indexer(['Upper Bound'])] = np.where(((df_p.iloc[i, df_p.columns.get_indexer(['Item Internal ID'])] == df_p.iloc[i+1, df_p.columns.get_indexer(['Item Internal ID'])])), df_p.iloc[i+1, df_p.columns.get_indexer(['From Quantity'])] - 1, 100000 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this with [`pandas.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) :

```
df["Upper Bound"] = df["From Quantity"].shift(-1).sub(1).fillna(1000, downcast="infer")
```

Output :
​

```
print(df)
​
  Item  From Quantity  Upper Bound
0    a              0           24
1    a             25           49
2    a             50         1000
```